# Filter phrases based on correspondent POS tags

Tags: python, text-mining, nltk

I have two lists:
The first one includes sentences and the second one includes parts of speech (POS) tags. I want to use POS tags as a filter and find phrases according to a pattern such as 'JJ JJ NNS' (adjective+adjective+noun)

How can I do that?

```
import re

key_list= [' techniques from nonlinear analysis and partial differential equations form the basis for these studies .', 
 ' in this case , center-manifold theory can be applied to study the ordinary differential equations which replace the nonlinear \
partial differential equations for the wave motion .', 
' differential equations are cool .']

value_list = ['NNS IN JJ NN CC JJ JJ NNS VBP DT NN IN DT NNS .',
 ' IN DT NN , JJ NN MD VB VBN TO VB DT JJ NN NNS WDT VB DT JJ JJ JJ NNS IN DT NN NN .', 
 ' JJ NNS VBP JJ .']

pattern= re.compile('JJ JJ NNS',re.M|re.DOTALL)

for value in value_list:
    value_output = pattern.findall(value)
    print(value_output)

# I want  partial differential equations and ordinary differential equations
```

Answer (score 3):

Hey,

Here's how i would solve this.
The problem with regex is that you don't have any index so I find it better to convert your inputs into lists of single words/tags by splitting on spaces. Then it is easier to find the pattern in the tag list and get the matching words.

```
words = [word for key in key_list for word in key.split()]  
tags = [tag for value in value_list for tag in value.split()]  

pattern = ['JJ', 'JJ', 'NNS']
matches = []

for i in range(len(tags)):
    if tags[i:i+len(pattern)] == pattern:
        matches.append(words[i:i+len(pattern)])

matches = [' '.join(match) for match in matches]
print(matches)

# result : ['partial differential equations', 'partial differential equations']
```

Also, if I'm not mistaken your pos-tagger marked "**differential**" as a noun (NN) in "**ordinary differential equations**". Nltk tagger does the job and it is really fast to implement but it is not perfect.

You can try using another tagger, I personally use the Stanford one for nlp processing.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. How can I add to the patterns? I will have several patterns and 'JJ', 'JJ', 'NNS' is only one of them.

Comment: You're welcome, to make this work for any patterns just replace the "pattern" variable :  eg. `pattern = ['DT', 'NN']`

Comment: I mean I have a list of patterns such as [['JJ', 'JJ', 'NNS'], ['JJ', 'NNS']]

Comment: Sorry, I went away for a while.I guess you can make a function out of it with `pattern, key_list and value_list` as arguments and call this function in a `for pattern in [['JJ', 'JJ', 'NNS'], ['JJ', 'NNS']] :`